# Cross-compiling and linking to a library in a sysroot - what's wrong?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, gnu-toolchain, wiringpi

I am not inexperienced but it's become clear to me that I lack some fundamental understanding in the area of cross-compilation and sysroots. I'm hoping someone can provide me that gem of information I need to continue.

I have downloaded a pre-built armhf gcc cross-compiler/toolchain and it came with a directory called `arm-linux-gnueabihf` that contains the following directories:

```
bin/
include/
lib/  - contains libstdc++.a, libgcc_s.so, but does NOT contain `libcrypt.so` or `libcrypt.so.1`, etc.
libc/
```

Curiously `libc` contains yet another set of directories, that looks a bit like a separate sysroot, but I'm not sure why it's here. I've looked in other toolchains, including one I built myself with crosstool-ng, and I've not seen anything similar:

```
libc/
     etc/
     lib/  - contains files like libcrypt.so.1 / libcrypt-2.24.so
     sbin/
     usr/
         bin/
         include/
         lib/  - contains files like libc.a, libc.so, libcrypt.a, libcrypt.so, 
         libexec/
         sbin/
         share/
     var/
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if that's a problem, or if I have to merge those two sysroots into one

I have installed it within a Docker container at the path `/cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1`. I am using cmake to cross-compile, and my toolchain.cmake file refers to this toolchain:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

This seems to be sufficient to build most code with the cross-compiler (including Boost).

As part of this container, I wish to have WiringPi installed in the sysroot, so I can build and link against it.

To do this, I have created a custom `CMakeLists.txt` file that successfully builds and installs WiringPi:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(WiringPi)
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
add_library(wiringPi SHARED ads1115.c <snip a bunch of .c files>)
target_include_directories(wiringPi PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(wiringPi PUBLIC ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} crypt m rt)
install(TARGETS wiringPi DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ads1115.h <snip a bunch of .h files>
        DESTINATION include)
```

This indicates that the resultant `libwiringpi.so` should be linked with `libcrypt`, `libpthread`, `libm` and `librt`. And if I run the target's `ldd` tool on `libwiringpi.so` it does indeed show these libraries as dependencies:

```
$ ldd libwiringPi.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7eee6000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0x76f0a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76ee0000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1 (0x76ea0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76e1e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x76e07000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76cb9000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f43000)
```

The problem I'm having is that I have an application that links against wiringpi using a cmake line like this:

```
target_link_libraries(myapp wiringPi)
```

When I build this on a raspberry pi using the native toolchain, I don't need to explicitly link against `libcrypt`. But in my Docker/cross-compiler environment, I get this error at link time:

```
/cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++     CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o   -o myapp -lpthread -lwiringPi -lrt 
/cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9.1.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libcrypt.so.1, needed by /cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9.1.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libwiringPi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9.1.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libwiringPi.so: undefined reference to `crypt@GLIBC_2.4'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that `-lrt` and `-lpthread` seem to have been automatically included in the link library list. But `-lcrypt` is not present.

If I copy/paste the `make VERBOSE=1` output that corresponds to this error, and manually add `-lcrypt` to the end of the command, it links successfully and the application compilation is complete.

I realise this is a long description but what I'm ultimately trying to do is find the hole in my knowledge that is preventing me from understanding why I would need to explicitly link `libcrypt` into this application in this environment.

I would have thought, perhaps wrongly, that since `libwiringpi.so` is already linked against `libcrypt`, that it wouldn't need to be linked at the top level. If that's not how it works, is there anyone that can help me repair my mental model, please?

Note: I could just add `target_link_libraries(myapp wiringPi crypt)` however I don't think it's necessary (not needed when building natively) and I'd like to learn a bit more about the process rather than just finding a workaround.

Comment: "I would have thought, perhaps wrongly, that since `libwiringpi.so` is already linked against `libcrypt`, that it wouldn't need to be linked at the top level." - Read the warning carefully: it says that `libcrypt.so.1` is **needed** by `libwiringPi.so`, but it **cannot find** `libcrypt.so.1` because it is not in RPATH. BTW, if the `/cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` is a **sysroot**, assign it to the [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) instead of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev does that mean that RPATH is used by the linker? I thought that was used to set the search path at run-time, not link time? I'd better brush up on this area. I'll also try the change you suggested - thank you.

EDIT: also, I'm not 100% sure what makes a sysroot a sysroot - `/cross-pi-gcc-9.1.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` contains some pre-built cross-compiled libraries (as described) and I've been installing boost, etc, into it as the process proceeds, so I guess it _is_ a sysroot?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I replaced `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` with `CMAKE_SYSROOT` and although that worked for cross-compiling Boost, it failed on WiringPi due to `ld` being unable to find `crt1.o`. It looks like this file is in that `libc` folder (see above for structure), but `CMAKE_SYSROOT` only takes one path, so would I need to manually merge the `libc` subdir with the main sysroot to make that work?

Comment: While `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` effectively re-root every path searched by CMake (with `find_*` calls), `CMAKE_SYSROOT` do the same both for CMake and for compiler/linker: that is, every path passed to the linker (except object files) is prepended by sysroot.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this myself...

It looks like the presence of the `libc` directory in the sysroot is unusual, and I checked other toolchains and it was always merged with `lib`. So I ended up ditching that particular toolchain and building my own with `crosstool-ng` instead. This avoided the problem entirely. It would be nice to understand how I might have got this working, but for now I must move on.

Note that I had success with just using `CMAKE_SYSROOT` only - no need in my case to specify `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and friends.