# Shared library dependency is not forwarded by a static library target when privately linked

Tags: gcc, cmake, cross-compiling

I have a complex CMake project where an executable links to a shared library. The shared library has a dependency on a static library. The static library in turn depends on other shared libraries.

A minimal self-containing project can be found here: https://github.com/rweickelt/stackoverflow/tree/cmake-transitive-dependencies

I repeat the CMake file here:

```cmake
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(SharedLibProblem C CXX)

# Manually setting output paths to simulate original project structure
# where all target sources live in various sub directories added by
# add_subdirectory()

add_library(TransitiveLib SHARED transitive.cpp)
set_target_properties(TransitiveLib PROPERTIES
    CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TransitiveLib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TransitiveLib"
    INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib"
)
target_compile_definitions(TransitiveLib PRIVATE BUILDING_LIBRARY)

add_library(StaticLib STATIC static.cpp)
set_target_properties(StaticLib PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/StaticLib"
)
target_link_libraries(StaticLib PUBLIC TransitiveLib)

add_library(SharedLib SHARED shared.cpp)
set_target_properties(SharedLib PROPERTIES
    CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SharedLib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SharedLib"
    INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib"
)
target_compile_definitions(SharedLib PRIVATE BUILDING_LIBRARY)

# StaticLib shall not leak any defines or headers to SharedLib.
# Thus it's private. But its link dependencies must be
# forwarded regardless.
target_link_libraries(SharedLib PRIVATE StaticLib)

add_executable(TheExecutable executable.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TheExecutable PRIVATE SharedLib)
set_target_properties(TheExecutable PROPERTIES
    CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TheExecutable"
    INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib"
)
```

Linking works when using the native x64 gcc on Linux. It also works with MSVC. But when building the project with the Raspbian GCC 10.2.0 toolchain, the final linking step fails:

```
[8/8] Linking CXX executable TheExecutable/TheExecutable
FAILED: TheExecutable/TheExecutable
: && /opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++   CMakeFiles/TheExecutable.dir/executable.cpp.o -o TheExecutable/TheExecutable  -Wl,-rpath,/mnt/c/Users/RichardWeickelt/projects/build/build-shared-lib-problem/SharedLib  SharedLib/libSharedLib.so && :
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libTransitiveLib.so, needed by SharedLib/libSharedLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: SharedLib/libSharedLib.so: undefined reference to `transitive_library_function()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I suspect that the cross-build fails because Raspbian GCC is configured with sysroot. Maybe that changes library search behavior. I have tried various things, including explicitly setting `-rpath-link` for all shared libraries.

I am tempted to simply set `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for every library target to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib` so that all dependent shared libraries in the build folder are always found.

But what's the canonical way to solve that problem? Linking a static library privately while keeping all shared library dependencies seems not unusual to me.

Comment: Setting variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` in the `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong by definition. It could be the very source of many weird errors, like the one you get. Instead, create a separate [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) and move into it all lines you have before `cmake_minimum_required`.

Comment: "I suspect that the cross-build fails because Raspbian GCC is configured with sysroot." - In that case your toolchain file should also set the variable [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html).

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is a minimal stripped-down project to show the issue.

Comment: "In that case your toolchain file should also set the variable CMAKE_SYSROOT" - where is that written? Is no effect here, btw.

Comment: `CMAKE_SYSROOT` should be set in the toolchain file. If you set this variable and CMake detects that your compiler supports `--sysroot` option, then CMake should pass that option to the compiler. You could easily check that by inspecting the command line. (The one in your post reflects the fact that `--sysroot` has not been added.) Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073824/cross-compiling-and-linking-to-a-library-in-a-sysroot-whats-wrong

Comment: I don't see how setting sysroot is related. It does also not solve the problem.

Comment: "I don't see how setting sysroot is related." - Then why do you write in your question post "I suspect that the cross-build fails because Raspbian GCC is configured with sysroot."? BTW, you definitely may find more details about your problem by checking RPATH-related things for the `libTransitiveLib.so` library which is created by CMake in the build directory. See e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348364/3440745) (make sure to use `readelf` or other utility from your toolchain).

Comment: " Then why do you write in your question post "I suspect that the cross-build fails because Raspbian GCC is configured with sysroot."" Because that's the only noticable difference between the host toolchain and the Raspbian toolchain. And the fact that we are cross-compiling now.

Comment: " BTW, you definitely may find more details about your problem by checking RPATH-related things for the libTransitiveLib.so library which is created by CMake in the build directory." But it doesn't find `libTransitive.so`. The RPATH/RUNPATH in the shared objects is exactly the same when comparing host build and raspbian build. It's the directory of the .so in the build folder. That looks correct to me.